# Show that the set $U$ contains the set $S$

Tags: calculus, analysis, set-theory, convex-analysis

I want to show that the set $U=\{\left(x, y\right)\in\mathbb R^2 \ | \ \left(x-1\right)^2 + \left(y-1\right)^2 <3\}$ contains the set $S=\{\left(x, y\right)\in\mathbb R^2 \ | \ x \geq1; \ y\geq0; \ x^2+y^2 \leq 4\}$

It is easy to see that $U$ contains $S$ graphically. But I don't know how to show it mathematically. If I can get a little hint, I will appreciate it.

Comment: That “for all $x$ and $y$” in the first sentence makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$U$ and $S$ are connected (and convex) subsets of the plane. To prove that $S \subseteq U$, it is enough to prove that:

1. One point of $S$, i.e. $(1,0)$ belongs to $U$.
2. And that the [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) of $S$ doesn't intersect the boundary of $U$.

The boundary of $U$ is the circle centered on the origin with radius $\sqrt 3$. And the boundary of $S$ is a portion of a circle plus two line segments.

Comment: Justifying that description of the boundary of $S$ _without_ resorting to geometric intuition is going to to be some work in itself, though. I think what is really needed is to challenge the OP's premise that a graphical argument is not "mathematical".

Comment: @Troposphere I understand what you mean but only partially agree. Observing the inclusion of a disk into another one can be done graphically. it can also be proven by looking at the position of the centers and the radii.

Comment: So by showing that the boundary $\partial S \in U$, then we can conclude that $S \subseteq U$

Comment: Yes because the boundary of $U$ being a circle, the boundary of $S$ should intersect it otherwise.

Comment: Please have a look at the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

$U$ and $S$ are connected (and convex) subsets of the plane. To prove that $S \subseteq U$ or $U \subseteq S$, you need to:

1. Find one point, i.e. $(1,0)$, that belongs to both of $S$ and $U$.
2. Prove that the boundary of $S$ doesn't intersect the boundary of $U$.

In addition, to prove specifically that $S \subseteq U$ you need to:

3. Find one point of $U$ that does not belong to $S$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am just trying to correct what is wrong with the accepted answer: the poof outlined only proves that $S$ belongs to $U$ or $U$ belongs to $S$, not specifically that $S$ belongs to $U$. And the move to delete the post I find proposterous since I am following the exact framework of the accepted answer which was not proposed for deletion.

Comment: You know, I believe my post is quite useful since it is adding math insight to the discussion that would have otherwise been lost considering I cannot comment on the accepted answer to point what is wrong with my current reputation score.